# Converting a string to date format throws error in informatica

Tags: informatica

I am trying to parse a string into date/time format. The input field is string '2023-04-25 11:35:11' and I am using below function to convert it to date/time format.

TO_DATE(input_string, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH:MM:SS')

Error message:

Transformation [Expression] had an error evaluating output column [Input_String]. Error message is [<> [TO_DATE]: invalid string for converting to Date ... t:TO_DATE(u:'2023-04-25 11:35:11',u:'YYYY-MON-DD HH:MM:SS')].

Can someone suggest what I am missing here?

Comment: Try the month format as MM rather than MON

Comment: Thank you for checking, I tried month format as MM still it is throwing similar error

Comment: i think you may have bad date format in data. can you pls check all the data in the column in source.